# Security for prepared SQL statement with REGEX in query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to use a prepared PDO statement for use in a database query that looks like the following, where the placeholders variables are represented by the numbers in quotes, i.e., "123" and "456":

```
SELECT `user_ID` as `ID` 
FROM `usermeta` 
WHERE (`meta_key` = 'custom_fields') 
AND (`meta_value` REGEXP '.*"ABC";.*s:[0-9]+:"123".*') 
AND (`meta_value` REGEXP '.*"DEF";.*s:[0-9]+:"456".*')
```

My question is, would the best practice be to bind to the whole REGEX expression, or just the "123" and "456" variables (is that even possible in a REGEX expression), or something wholly different?

In other words, which is preferred, this:

```
SELECT `user_ID` as `ID` 
FROM `usermeta` 
WHERE (`meta_key` = 'custom_fields') 
AND (`meta_value` :REGEXP1) 
AND (`meta_value` :REGEXP2)

$stmt->bindParam(':REGEXP1', "REGEXP '.*"ABC";.*s:[0-9]+:"123".*'");
$stmt->bindParam(':REGEXP2', "REGEXP '.*"DEF";.*s:[0-9]+:"456".*'");
```

Or this?  (I know there would be some issues with double quotes surrounding the placeholder.)

```
SELECT `user_ID` as `ID` 
FROM `usermeta` 
WHERE (`meta_key` = 'custom_fields') 
AND (`meta_value` REGEXP '.*"ABC";.*s:[0-9]+:":value1".*') 
AND (`meta_value` REGEXP '.*"DEF";.*s:[0-9]+:":value2".*')

$stmt->bindParam(':value1', '123');
$stmt->bindParam(':value2', '456');
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placeholders can't be quoted. Simple as that:

```
SELECT ... WHERE foo = ?
SELECT ... WHERE foo = '?'
```

The first one is a placeholder, and works as expected. The other one is testing for equality against the character "question mark". It's not a placeholder anymore.

And then there's the problem of `?` being a regex metacharacter as well. If placeholders COULD be quoted, then given

```
SELECT ... WHERE foo REGEXP '^.?'
```

would that `?` be a query placeholder, or is it the regex "zero-or-one" range operator?

If you want to use placeholders in regexes, you have to "build" the regex pattern

```
SELECT ... WHERE foo REGEXP concat('^.', ?)
```

Exactly the same way as you would have to build a `LIKE` pattern:

```
SELECT ... WHERE foo LIKE '%?%' // wrong
SELECT ... WHERE foo LIKE concat('%', ?, '%') // right
```